# Generate warning when using global variables in Perl

Tags: perl, warnings, global

Is there a way to generate a warning if a Perl subroutine is using a global variable?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w  
use strict;
my $GlobalVariable;

#  Main Start

#  Main End

sub  MyFunction
{
    my $LocalVariable;
    $GlobalVariable=1;

}
```

In this code is there anyway in Perl to warn that `MyFunction()` is using `$GlobalVariable` ?

Comment: People will suggest [strict](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?strict), but there are exceptions to its checks. Sub names aren't checked (`$foo` dies, but not `foo()`), and neither are globs (`$foo` dies, but not `*foo` or `print foo`). Also, strict produces exceptions, not warnings.

Answer (score 2):

A standard practice is to `use strict 'vars';`.
After you typed this you'll have to fully qualify global variables (e.g. `$main::GlobalVar`) or Perl will throw a compile-time error.

- [perldoc strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html)

Comment: Perl will allow a subroutine to use a global variable even with use strict; Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just `use strict` and it will catch attempt to access any variable unless you explicitly declare it as local or global or fully qualify its name. You can try to `tie` access to current's package global scope (it is a hash after all) to catch access even to declared variables, but it is not recommended, since there are many legitimate reasons to do so (for example all that nice stuff from `perlodc perlvar`).

Comment: Parent comment misses the point of the question.  Look at the code above, it is using strict, and using a global variable in a sub.  Strict does *NOT* throw a warning in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "warn if the Perl code uses any global variables", I don't think there is currently a predefined way to do this.

If you wanted to just disallow the use of any non-standard Perl global variables, you could use something like Devel::FindGlobals from CPAN to get all of the global variables, then warn if there are any non-standard global variables defined.